# Unable to use simplejson.loads() on a string

Tags: python, json, simplejson

I am trying to use `simplejson.loads(source_urls)` to turn `JSON` into a Python object.

```
source_urls = [u'http://www.google.com', u'http://www.yahoo.com', u'http://www.facebook.com']
```

That line is from logger output. As much as that looks like a list, it is actually stored as a string in the database.

I get the following error:

```
JSONDecodeError:
Expecting object: line 1 column 1 (char 1)
```

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: That looks exactly like a line of Python code.  I don't see any JSON anywhere.  Why do you have strings like that in the db?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you really have a single string `source_urls` containing:

```
"[u'http://www.google.com', u'http://www.yahoo.com', u'http://www.facebook.com']"
```

you can do:

```
import ast
urls = ast.literal_eval(source_urls)
```

This will not allow true code execution.  It only handles "strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None".

Comment: ast feels lightning fast comparing to the json module

Answer (score 1):

All strings in JSON must be enclosed by double quotes. Refernece: http://simonwillison.net/2006/oct/11/json/

```
source_urls = '["http://www.google.com", "http://www.yahoo.com", 
                "http://www.facebook.com"]'
simplejson.loads(source_urls)
['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.yahoo.com', 'http://www.facebook.com']
```

Looks like the source_urls string is not encoded by simplejson.dumps.. Hope this helps..